# How to dismiss formSheet Modal from ParentViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm making a modal view that presents when the user touch up on a button. At the moment, I already show the modal and I can use that modal interface.

Now I wan't to dismiss the modal when a button inside the modal is pressed and after that do a segue from it's parent to another view.

```
let summary = SummaryViewController(nibName: "SummaryViewController", bundle: nil)
summary.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 800, height: 300)
summary.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.formSheet
self.present(summary, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

SummaryViewController have the following code:

```
import UIKit

class SummaryViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var summaryTV: UITextView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    summaryTV.delegate = self
    summaryTV.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    summaryTV.text = "Escriba el resumen de la visita"
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }


  func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.textColor ==  UIColor.lightGray {
      textView.text = nil
      textView.textColor = UIColor.black
    }
  }
  func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.text.isEmpty {
      textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
      textView.text = "Escriba el resumen de la visita"
    }
  }

  @IBAction func saveSummary(_ sender: Any) {
    print("SummaryTV: \(summaryTV.text)")
  }

  // MARK: Segues
  // Overrided functions for segues. Ordered according to segue flow.
  override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    // If false, segue cancelled. Segue identifier is a parameter of the function.
    // If you use function 'performSegue()' flow do not pass this function.
    if !Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() {
      CommonAlerts.inetAlert(vc: self)
      return false
    }
    return true
  }
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

  }
}
```

So when the user press the button inside the modal view, the IBAction `saveSummary` is triggered. In that moment I want the parent view controller who present the modal to capture the text on the modal and dismiss the modal. How can I do it?

Comment: In the same ParentViewController, I have a Menu presented as `UIModalPresentationStyle.popover` and I delegate the presentation to the ParentViewController. With this I can manage the dismiss with the function `popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover`. For some reason I don't understand I can't use the same function with the modal presentation `formSheet`.

Comment: You can create a protocol in your modal class and let your parent conform to that protocol. So when the modal is being dismissed just call your delegate method which will trigger the delegate function in the parent. So in that protocol method you can do anything you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@IBAction func saveSummary(_ sender: Any) {
    print("SummaryTV: \(summaryTV.text)")

    self.presentingViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false,
          completion: nil)
  }
```

As for communication, you can setup a weak delegate to presenting VC which will implement a protocol:

```
protocol SummaryResult {
   func saveResult(summary: String)
}
```